# How to create a .crt from a signature json object of a private update centre to Authorise jenkins to update plugins

Tags: authentication, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I work in an Enterprise with very strict security.
They operate a private jenkins-plugin-repo that I would connect to using an update centre.
The url of the update centre is in the form of https://xyz/update-centre.json, and has a signature object on its page in the form of:

"signature": {
"certificates": ["sring"],
"correct_digest": "string",
"correct_signature": "string",
"digest": "string",
"signature": "string"
}
There are some instructions from few years ago about how to connect to it:
I have installed the jenkins plugin "update-sites-manager.hpi" and tried the following:

1. (first trial) inserted the update-centre url in the Manage Jenkins -> Plugin Manager -> Update Site: url box (see screenshot at the bottom) and in: Manage Jenkins -> Manage Update Sites -> url (see screenshot at the bottom), then added the ID field there as well and added the certificate string above from the json into a new directory %jenkins_home%/update-center-rootCAs/my-cert.crt then restarted jenkins and got error: there were errors checking the update sits: Signature verification failed in update site
2. (second trial) pasted the certificate string in the json above into the CA certificate box in jenkins in: Manage Jenkins -> Manage update Sites (see screenshot at the bottom) but resulted in the same error above

From the error messages I think the certificate i am using is probably wrong/not in the right format, and I do not know how to correct that?
My Jenkins is 2.222.3 running from a docker container based on jdk11 within a RHEL 7 VM.
I am a C# developer, not so familiar with certs.
Also the page above (https://xyz/update-centre.json) does not have a certificate associate that appears normally upon clicking on a padlock left to the url box: the padlock does nto exist.

First try:

`Manage Jenkins -> Plugins Manager`
[image: Manage Jenkins -> Plugins Manager]

`Manage Jenkins -> Manage Update Sites`
[image: Manage Jenkins -> Manage Update Sites]

Second try:

`Manage Jenkins -> Manage Update Sites`
[image: Manage Jenkins -> Manage Update Sites]